# Strech Bone Constrain problem

Tags: bones, constraints

I have a bone with stretch constrain, when I try to move the target bone, the stretch bone goes crazy doing things not related wuth the movement i do with the mouse.

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is the target bone parented to the stretched bone? I know that causes issues with certain constraints, not sure about stretch to though. Try clearing the parent of the target bone (alt p I believe).

Comment: Yes. That solved the issue! ThankYou!

Answer (score 2):

This issue have been solved by cleaning the parent of the target bone, wich was the stretching bone itself. This chain of parenting is not the correct usage of armature bones and constraints.

Comment: Just to clarify why that happened, basically you created a loop, where the target bone tells the stretched bone where to be (via the constraint), and the stretched bone tells the target where to be (via the parent). Since they refer to each other, there's no way to solve where the position actually should be.

Comment: Exactly! ... Seen my other issues in rigging I start to see thats the problem in my riggs ... (and my life) So I can solve it now ;) Thanks